# JavaScript Check if an array contains any element of another array and if it does append new div to class

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, append

I am 90% of the way there I am just struggling to get my code to add a div at the begging of an item if it is apart of my sale array to call out a sale. This has to be done using Global Javascript only thanks to Google O.

```
<div class="cart table-wrapper">
  <table id="shopping-cart-table" class="cart items data table">
    <tbody class="cart item"></tbody>
    <div class="product-item-details">
      <strong class="product-item-name"> Item that is on Sale </strong>
      <strong class="product-sku"> Item # 19858836 </strong>
    </div>
    <tbody class="cart item">
      <div class="product-item-details">
        <strong class="product-item-name"> Item that is not on sale </strong>
        <strong class="product-sku"> Item # 20278541 </strong>
      </div>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
const arr = ["Item # 19858836", "Item # 19858837"]; 

const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('product-sku');
const positions = Array.from(elements).map(element => element.innerText);

positions.forEach(function(item){
  if(arr.includes(item)){
    let saleCallout = document.createElement('div');
    saleCallout.id = 'saletime';
    saleCallout.id = 'Extra Money Already Taken Off';
    
    document.querySelector('.product-item-details').appendChild(saleCallout);

    } else {
      //do nothing
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b5t6e1zw/1/

Comment: Your question is…? Best to post a minimal example that demonstrates the issue **here**, along with expected result, actual result and any error messages.

Comment: The second assignment to *saleCallout.id* replaces the value assigned in the first assignment. Perhaps it should be `saleCallut.textContent = ...` BTW, there's no need for *map*, you could do `document.querySelectorAll('.product_sku').forEach(el => if(arr.includes(el.textContent)){...})`. Lastly, `["Item # 19858836", "Item # 19858837"].includes('Item # 1985')` is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is trying to match the text content of an element with a string value. You should reduce the characters to match to a minimum and put the matching value as an element attribute so you can be sure it matches.

In the OP, you're trying to see if "Item # 19858836" includes " Item # 1985 ", which wont work because the second has a leading space and the first doesn't.

Anyway, you can make this example work by trimming the element's textContent before doing *includes*:

```js
let data = ["Item # 19858836", "Item # 19858837"]; 

// Get the elements and loop over them
document.querySelectorAll('.product-sku').forEach(el => { 

  // If the element text content is in the data array,
  // add an element
  if (data.some(item => item.includes(el.textContent.trim()))) {
    let saleCallout = document.createElement('div');
    saleCallout.id = 'saletime';
    saleCallout.textContent = 'Extra Money Already Taken Off';
    el.parentNode.appendChild(saleCallout);
//    document.querySelector('.product-item-details').appendChild(saleCallout);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="cart table-wrapper">
  <table id="shopping-cart-table" class="cart items data table">
    <tbody class="cart item"></tbody>
    <div class="product-item-details">
      <strong class="product-item-name"> Item that is on Sale </strong>
      <strong class="product-sku"> Item # 1985 </strong>
    </div>
    <tbody class="cart item">
      <div class="product-item-details">
        <strong class="product-item-name"> Item that is not on sale </strong>
        <strong class="product-sku"> Item # 2027 </strong>
      </div>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you use *querySelectorAll* then you don't need to convert the elements collection to an array, you can use the collection's *forEach* method directly.

Also likely that the saleCallout node should be added after the element that matched, not just to the first element with class "product-item-details".